# Log errors from app on Google Play using Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, google-play, crashlytics

Probably silly question, but is it possible to send errors using Crashlytics from users that downloaded my app from Google Play? Until now I was using Crashlytics to collect errors from my app distributed by Firebase (so it was only for me and invited people). But I have released my app on Google Play and I can't see any errors from devices that downloaded my app in Google Play. I read that when I link my Google app with Firebase I can see purchase and subscription and analytics but no mention of Crashlytics. So my question is.. Is it even possible? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally made it..

I'd like to thanks to @cactustictacs for help.
The problem was that I did not integrate Google Play in project settings in Firebase, although it is saying that it is just for Analytics and Subscription.

Before I integrated Google Play in Firebase I tried to add `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)` .. it did not work, but I believe it could be usefull to someone.

It wouldn't be such a problem, but it is required to have Owner or Admin permissions on both Firebase account and Google Play console account (which I did not have). After I get the permissions, integration was enabled and I could see test crashes in Crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

Is the package name the same on your "release" version on the store? If your test one was called `com.patrik.coolapp.debug` (which is the default if you're using a debug build) then you'll need to add `com.patrik.coolapp` as an **App** in your **Project** in the Firebase console.

If you already had Crashlytics [set up](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) (all the dependencies, added the plugin, `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)` somewhere in your app) then it should just work - here's some advice on testing:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The package name is the same on the store as the one on Firebase. I am pretty sure, that I set up Crashlytics correctly (from doc). But still I can see only crashes on firebase from devices that installed my app from firebase. When crash occur on application from Google play, there is nothing. I did not set `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)` that you mentioned, do you think it is the reason? And I have not integrated Google Play in Firebase, but they are saying that it is only for subscription and analytics purpose.

Comment: And another question that comes to my mind.. Do I have to add new version of AAB file that is on Google Play to Firebase release or not? I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: I don't really know anything about making releases available through Firebase, sorry! But Crashlytics will handle multiple app versions (obviously, since not all your users will update) so it shouldn't be an issue. And Crashlytics *should* be enabled by default, but enabling collection will make sure (and also allow you to toggle it off while debugging). What I'd do first, is make sure a release APK (installed direct from Android Studio) is sending reports to Firebase. That's easier to troubleshoot. Also crash reports are only sent the next time the app is started, if that's relevant!